# VSCode not output DataFrame with HTML format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

Currently, I'm having problems with when viewing DataFrame on VSCode.

I cannot see the DataFrame format as on Jupyter Notebook. My DataFrame is displayed as follows:

Output Exceeds The ***Size Limit***. Open The Full Output Data ***in A Text Editor***:

I tried the methods:

- Remove and new install Conda-Forge
- Install and re-run on a new environment

[This view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQIbe.png)

**Update (23/02/2022)**

I fixed `"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"` in `settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Command Palette` -> `Preferences: Oper User Settings`

Then find this option:

```
Notebook › Output: Text Line Limit
Control how many lines of text in a text output is rendered.
```

Just increase the value as much as you want and close the window.